# How can I maintain the headers for my JSON data after aggregation?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I am developing a REST API in mongoDB with pymongo. I have several endpoints to execute different queries. I want the JSON data created to maintain the headers it had in the original JSON file.

This is the original JSON data.
`"player": "Jamie Vardy", "team": "Leicester City", "assists": 5,`

After my endpoint is executed the data returned looks like this:

```
5, 
"Jamie Vardy", 
"Leicester City",
```

The endpoint:

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/players/top-assister", methods=["GET"])
def top_assister():

pipeline = [ { "$match" : { "assists" : {"$gte" : 12} } },
             { "$project" : {"assists" : 1, "player" : 1, "team":1}}
            ]

top_assister = []
for player in players.aggregate(pipeline):
    player["assists"]
    str(player["player"])
    str(player["team"])
    
    top_assister.append([player["assists"], str(player["player"]), str(player["team"])])

return make_response(jsonify(top_assister), 200)
```

Comment: I think you don't need the _for-in_ loop. You can directly get a _list_ using this: `list(db.things.aggregate(pipeline))` (see Pymongo Tutorials - [Aggregation Example](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/aggregation.html)). And, pass the list to the response.

Comment: maybe you should apped  dict instead list - `apped ({"assists": player["assists"], "player": player["player"], "team": player["team"]})`. Or maybe you should put directly `player` in `append(player)`

Comment: @furas Thanks appending dict solved my problem